# HTML5 - Multiple input field: file limit?

Tags: html, input, limit

Im using the HTML 5 input element with the multiple option set to true:

```
<input type="file" id="input" multiple="true" onchange="handleFiles(this.files)">
```

This works, but when I use it to select more then 388 images, the file name box stays empty and the code doesn't work. If I select less then  388 images, I can run my code. Is there some kind of limit on the number of files you can select? I tried to run the mozilla drag and drob application:
http://demos.hacks.mozilla.org/openweb/DnD/
 with 456 files, and this works perfect. But I would also like to have a simple browse button which allows me to select all the files I want. Any idea is highly appreciated!

Thanks,

Comment: What happens if you select exactly 388 images? And do you get an error message in the console?

Comment: I can select all the images from 0 until 388 (including 388). So basically I'm able to select 389 images. Selecting number 389 and onwards makes the file name box go blank. Could it be that there are to many characters in the input field? I don't get an error in the console. Thanks for your comment

Comment: Is this behavior consistent with the other browsers?  Or is this a FF thing?

Answer (score -1):

set server's `upload_max_filesize`, `post_max_size`, `memory_limit`, ...